# Word Automation to pdf

Tags: pdf, ms-word, pdf-generation, word-automation

What is the best free Word library out there I can use in my c# application for word automation. Working with the Interop library is really difficult.

After I have generated the word documents is there also a good free pdf library I can use ?

Comment: in terms of pdf conversion- try [pdfcreator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/)

Answer (score 0):

You could try the UNO library provided by the free OpenOffice suite. Here is an example:
http://tinyway.wordpress.com/2011/03/30/how-to-convert-office-documents-to-pdf-using-open-office-in-c/

Comment: In terms of speed is this library faster than MS Interop ?